# confusion regarding handling of new smart pointers on stack frames?

Tags: c++11, stack, smart-pointer

Let me try to elaborate it.

**Stack Frame:** When we execute any function it create stack where all local variables and instructions reside.
 And **Smart Pointer:** smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` allows to change ownership of object inside of smart pointer.

Now my confusion is: suppose we pass a `unique_ptr` from a *source function* to a *target function*, the `rvalue` will be assigned to target pointer by `std::move`. Now if the function exits, the stack frame will deallocated. So will `unique_ptr` in target function be a dangling pointer, since `unique_ptr` is pointing to same memory location that resides in source function's stack frame?

One thing I thought is, since target function lifetime will be over before source function's lifetime. So that wont cause any such side effects. But in more complex applications with multi threaded environment, how does it go? Or what do we need to take care of?

Answer (score 3):

You're conflating two things: *scope*, which governs the lifetime of objects, and *stack frames*, which are an implementation detail, and aren't relevant here.

> Now my confusion is suppose we pass unique_ptr from source function to target function, The rvalue will be assigned to target pointer by std::move

So you've explicitly *moved* ownership from the caller's `unique_ptr` object (in the source function) to the callee's `unique_ptr` (in the target function). The source's `unique_ptr` object *no longer owns anything*, and you can't dereference it.

Now, when the target function returns (or throws an exception - anything that causes its scope to exit), and the target's `unique_ptr` object is destroyed, it will delete the object previously owned by the caller's `unique_ptr`.

Control then returns to the source function, whose `unique_ptr` is still in scope but no longer owns anything. There's nothing you can usefully do with this object except assign it a new pointer to control.